# Probabilistic inequalities involving random variables on both sides?

Tags: inequality, probability-distributions, exponential-distribution, cumulative-distribution-functions

Can I break down $P(h \geq (A + B)$, given all $ A,B,h$ are all random variables. Will the following rule works?

$$P[h \geq (A + B)] = P(h\geq A) +  P(h\geq B)$$

Actually, in one of my mathematical analysis, I end up with a complex expression which can be simplified to $P[h \geq (A + B)]$. I believe I can move forward if I can break it down somehow. Further explanations of variables are as below.

> $h \sim \exp(\lambda')$ and $g \sim \exp(\lambda'')$

> $A = a(1 + e^{sh})$, $B = bg(1+e^{sh})$

$a,b,s, \lambda', \lambda''$ are constants.

Comment: If the rv are positive, then clearly the statement can't be true, since $P(h \geq A + B) < P(h \geq A)$

Comment: Thanks. Can you then suggest how I can solve the expression $P[h> (A+B)]$

Comment: I do not know what you mean by "solve it". Also, that's not what your question is asking for. So, please state what is it that you're looking for.

Comment: Yes. My question does not ask for the solution directly, but this is what I am looking for. By solving I mean the simplified final expression for the event $P[ h> (A+B)]$. But I suppose I should pose another question for the solution as this question has a different ask.

Comment: In general, there isn't s nice simple expression for $P(h > A + B)$. So, it would likely be best to pose what it is that you're truly going for.

Answer (score 2):

As has already been stated, your approach does not work. Here is an idea: Since $h,g$ are independent (this has not directly been stated in the question but I assume it's true), the following should hold: \begin{align*}\textbf{P}(h\geq A+B)&=\textbf{P}(h\geq(1+e^{sh})(a+bg))=\textbf{P}(h\geq(1+e^{sh})(a+bg))\\&=\textbf{P}(h/(1+e^{sh})\geq(a+bg))=\textbf{E}[\textbf{P}(h/(1+e^{sh})\geq(a+bg)|h)]\\&=\textbf{E}[F_g((h/(1-e^{sh})-a)/b)]\end{align*} where $F_g$ is the CDF of $g$. This is the case if $b>0$. Cases $b=0$ and $b<0$ follow analogously.